# How to de-activate (remove) the "confirm you want to leave this page" on an un-submitted form?

Tags: javascript, ajax, forms, safari

I have an AJAX auto-save input fields on my page which rocks! 
The problem is that in Safari, when the user leaves the page, he gets a warning

- "Are you sure you want to leave without submitting the form?"

which obviously **I don't want**.

How can I get rid of it!?!

[image]

So the **opposite** of such post: [Dont ask confirm if user submit the form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14624843/dont-ask-confirm-if-user-submit-the-form)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

when that message pops up this event is fired: onbeforeunload. just add this to your javascript code to remove this event:

```
window.onbeforeunload = null;
```